Baking hair on to a normal map
How can i bake the hair particles to a normal map?
If i try to convert hair to mesh, and do it normally, blender doesn’t do it, since the mesh does not have any faces.
I tried using the skin modifier to give the strands some thickness, and while it did work, and i managed to bake the particles to this plane, it is horribly laggy, and blender just crashes if i try to to use it for anything more complex than this quick test

